# I want to get my data-set value no matter where i click within the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, guys please visit my codeSnippet. I can't find an answer to this question anywhere been trying this for 3 days now..

What i want to achieve

1. User clicks the button.
2. It shows the 3 boxes with a red border.
3. Tapping anywhere in the red box should give me fruit name of that box

The problem now is: It works when i click on certain areas but other areas give me undefined. I thought of calling the div widget instead of the allresults div like this in my last line of the js part but nothing happens no alert at all:

```
$('#widget').on('click',  testAlert);
```

```js
$("#test").on('click',  begin);

function begin(){
  var test = ["apple","pear","banana"];
  var test2 = ["fish", "bird", "insect"];
  var test3 = ["iOS", "Android", "Windows"];
  var test4 = ["Mom", "Dad", "Sis"];
  
  for (var i=0; i < test.length; i++){
    
    var listItem = document.createElement('div'),
    html = "<p id='one'>" + test[i] + '</p>' 
         + "<p id='two'> " + test2[i] + '</p>'
         + "<p id='three'>" + test3[i] + '</p>'
         + "<p id='four'> " + test4[i] + '</p>';
     listItem.id='widget';
                  
      
    listItem.dataset.fruit = test[i];
    listItem.innerHTML = html;
    allresults.appendChild(listItem);
  }
}

function testAlert(e){
  var fruit = e.target.dataset.fruit; 
    alert(fruit);
}

$('#allresults').on('click',  testAlert);
```

```css
#one{
  margin-left:12%;
  padding-top:8%;
  color:black;
  font-family:arial;
  font-size:15px;
}

#two{
  margin-left:3%;
  color:black;
  font-family:arial;
  font-size:17px;
  line-height:5px;
}

#three{
  margin-left:3%;
  color:black;
  font-family:arial;
  font-size:12px;
  line-height:10px;
}

#four{
  margin-left:3%;
  padding-bottom:8%;
  color:black;
  font-family:testFont1;
  font-size:12px;
  line-height:-10px;
}

#widget{
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="searchResults">        
    <div id="allresults" >              
    </div>        
</div>

<button id=test>click me</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [attach an event handler to the dynamically-created DIV elements](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/#event-propagation), not `#allresults`.

```js
$("#test").on('click',  function (){
  var test = ["apple","pear","banana"];
  var test2 = ["fish", "bird", "insect"];
  var test3 = ["iOS", "Android", "Windows"];
  var test4 = ["Mom", "Dad", "Sis"];
  
  for (var i=0; i < test.length; i++){
    
    var listItem = document.createElement('div'),
    html = "<p id='one'>" + test[i] + '</p>' 
         + "<p id='two'> " + test2[i] + '</p>'
         + "<p id='three'>" + test3[i] + '</p>'
         + "<p id='four'> " + test4[i] + '</p>';
     listItem.id='widget';
                  
      
    listItem.dataset.fruit = test[i];
    listItem.innerHTML = html;
    allresults.appendChild(listItem);
  }
});


// add an onclick handler to dynamically-created DIV
$('#allresults').on('click', 'div', function () {
  var fruit = this.dataset.fruit; 
    alert(fruit);
});
```

```css
#one{
  margin-left:12%;
  padding-top:8%;
  color:black;
  font-family:arial;
  font-size:15px;
}

#two{
  margin-left:3%;
  color:black;
  font-family:arial;
  font-size:17px;
  line-height:5px;
}

#three{
  margin-left:3%;
  color:black;
  font-family:arial;
  font-size:12px;
  line-height:10px;
}

#four{
  margin-left:3%;
  padding-bottom:8%;
  color:black;
  font-family:testFont1;
  font-size:12px;
  line-height:-10px;
}

#widget{
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="searchResults">        
    <div id="allresults" >              
    </div>        
</div>

<button id=test>click me</button>
```

Comment: You ma man are the best! Finally after 3 days! Thanks a lot mikey!

Comment: actually the the event handler can be attached to #allresults (as did in my answer below), but we should check if it is the true element or we need its parentElement. Your method works here, but in a more general case, if he use DIV also for child elements (instead of P) then it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the e.target on click can be the child (p) element inside your widget div elements. In this case, you have to access its parent element as following:

```
function testAlert(e){
  var t = e.target;
  if (t.id != "widget") t = t.parentElement;
  var fruit = t.dataset.fruit; 
  alert(fruit);
}
```

here is the full snippet:

```js
$("#test").on('click',  begin);

function begin(){
  var test = ["apple","pear","banana"];
  var test2 = ["fish", "bird", "insect"];
  var test3 = ["iOS", "Android", "Windows"];
  var test4 = ["Mom", "Dad", "Sis"];
  
  for (var i=0; i < test.length; i++){
    
    var listItem = document.createElement('div'),
    html = "<p id='one'>" + test[i] + '</p>' 
         + "<p id='two'> " + test2[i] + '</p>'
         + "<p id='three'>" + test3[i] + '</p>'
         + "<p id='four'> " + test4[i] + '</p>';
     listItem.id='widget';
      
    listItem.dataset.fruit = test[i];
    listItem.innerHTML = html;
    allresults.appendChild(listItem);
  }
}

function testAlert(e){
 var t = e.target;
 if (t.id != "widget") t = t.parentElement;
 var fruit = t.dataset.fruit; 
    alert(fruit);
}

$('#allresults').on('click',  testAlert);
```

```css
#one{
  margin-left:12%;
  padding-top:8%;
  color:black;
  font-family:arial;
  font-size:15px;
}

#two{
  margin-left:3%;
  color:black;
  font-family:arial;
  font-size:17px;
  line-height:5px;
}

#three{
  margin-left:3%;
  color:black;
  font-family:arial;
  font-size:12px;
  line-height:10px;
}

#four{
  margin-left:3%;
  padding-bottom:8%;
  color:black;
  font-family:testFont1;
  font-size:12px;
  line-height:-10px;
}

#widget{
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="searchResults">        
    <div id="allresults" >              
    </div>        
</div>

<button id=test>click me</button>
```